# C# methods with no body

Tags: c#, methods

I'm new to C# and have come across stuff like this in the codebase I'll be working on (these specific examples are from Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils).

```
public CommandArgument Argument(string name, string description, Action<CommandArgument> configuration, bool multipleValues = false);
public CommandArgument Argument(string name, string description, bool multipleValues = false);
```

I really just want to know what this construct is called and what's actually going on when you call these functions? I'm guessing they are proxies with some compile time magic but not sure.

Comment: Please link to the full code. Being public makes it not part of an interface and not being abstract makes it impossible to have no implementation

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you posted is not legal C♯, and it doesn't actually appear in [the source of `Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils` anywhere](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/dev/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources/CommandLine/CommandLineApplication.cs#L95-L114).

Comment: Yea this has been answered by @Lanorkin - actually viewing meta information for an external DLL

Thanks for the source link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a valid C# code.

Most probably you clicked "Go to Definition" / F12 in VS.Net, and you were presented with metadata of external DLL.

Comment: This is exactly what happened. I wanted to know what the class was doing and was presented with all sorts of weird stuff. 

So when you say external DLL - does this mean I cannot peek into how this is working?

If I wanted to see how Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils works I couldn't view source (prob a completely stupid questions - but I'm coming from Go and Python where its possible to view source).

Comment: @opalfroot no you cannot. You have to decompile DLL or reference to sources if you have any. Resharper plugin (not free) can decompile on the fly for you inside visual studio. Or you can use dotPeek (free) for the same purpose, but outside of VS

Comment: For some of the OS stuff as others have shown I can view code on GitHub but as you say for everything else there's decompilation tools and the like.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are looking at is Visual Studio's generated code that it created from metadata (you'll see "generated from metadata" in the tab's title). This code doesn't actually compile - it's just to show you what the method signatures look like.

As you can see from [the actual code](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/959d7c48004cc77536ac550541c38c776c0133d4/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources/CommandLine/CommandLineApplication.cs#L95), these methods do have bodies.